# Methods from onvif are producing "AnySimpleType.pytonvalue() not implemented"

Tags: methods, onvif

while I'm trying to get a live stream from my IP camera in ONVIF format I used the streaming.py (https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep).

Unfortunately I get the error "AnySimpleType.pytonvalue() not implemented". I also get the latest zeep implementation by using

```
pip install --upgrade onvif_zeep
```

I don't know why the Methods in the example code aren't implemented. Here's the complete code:

```
    from onvif import ONVIFCamera

def media_profile_configuration():
    '''
    A media profile consists of configuration entities such as video/audio
    source configuration, video/audio encoder configuration,
    or PTZ configuration. This use case describes how to change one
    configuration entity which has been already added to the media profile.
    '''

    # Create the media service
    mycam = ONVIFCamera('****', ****, '****', '****')
    media_service = mycam.create_media_service()

    profiles = media_service.GetProfiles()

    # Use the first profile and Profiles have at least one
    token = profiles[0]._token

    # Get all video encoder configurations
    configurations_list = media_service.GetVideoEncoderConfigurations()

    # Use the first profile and Profiles have at least one
    video_encoder_configuration = configurations_list[0]

    # Get video encoder configuration options
    options = media_service.GetVideoEncoderConfigurationOptions({'ProfileToken':token})

    # Setup stream configuration
    video_encoder_configuration.Encoding = 'H264'
    # Setup Resolution
    video_encoder_configuration.Resolution.Width = \
                    options.H264.ResolutionsAvailable[0].Width
    video_encoder_configuration.Resolution.Height = \
                    options.H264.ResolutionsAvailable[0].Height
    # Setup Quality
    video_encoder_configuration.Quality = options.QualityRange.Min
    # Setup FramRate
    video_encoder_configuration.RateControl.FrameRateLimit = \
                                    options.H264.FrameRateRange.Min
    # Setup EncodingInterval
    video_encoder_configuration.RateControl.EncodingInterval = \
                                    options.H264.EncodingIntervalRange.Min
    # Setup Bitrate
    video_encoder_configuration.RateControl.BitrateLimit = \
                            options.Extension.H264[0].BitrateRange[0].Min[0]

    # Create request type instance
    request = media_service.create_type('SetVideoEncoderConfiguration')
    request.Configuration = video_encoder_configuration
    # ForcePersistence is obsolete and should always be assumed to be True
    request.ForcePersistence = True

    # Set the video encoder configuration
    media_service.SetVideoEncoderConfiguration(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    media_profile_configuration()
```

Has anyone an idea why I can't access the Methods to configurate the camera?

Comment: So I found out that the path of wdsl (last parameter from ONVIFCamera) only shows to "devicemgmt.wsdl". But if I call "media_service.GetProfiles()" the media.wdsl isn't available.

Comment: I found a workaround. I import the zeep library and wrote a method called "zeep_pythonvalue(self, xmlvalue)". It only returns the second parameter. At least I call "zeep.xsd.AnySimpleType.pythonvalue = zeep_pythonvalue". Then the methods are valid and everything works fine.

Comment: Hi @McProgger can you share the method zeep_pythonvalue(self.xmlvalue) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment on his question, and trial and error I managed to fix the error.

In your .py, add these codes:

```
import zeep

def zeep_pythonvalue(self,xmlvalue):
    return xmlvalue

zeep.xsd.AnySimpleType.pythonvalue = zeep_pythonvalue
```